# CVS Is Enabled, but Intellij Cannot Find It

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cvs

I am trying to check a project out of a CVS repo.  I have the CVS plugin enabled.  According to the documentation:

- IntelliJ IDEA comes bundled with CVS plugin. This plugin is turned on by default. If it is not, make sure that the plugin is enabled.
- IntelliJ IDEA's CVS integration does not require a standalone CVS client. All you need is an account in your CVS repository.
- CVS integration is enabled for the current project root or directory.

I think I have met all these requirements, but yet I get the following message when I try to browse a CVS repo, or checkout a project:

***Cannot run program "cvs"  CreateProcess error = 2, The system cannot find the file specified***

In ~\IntelliJIDEA14.1.4\plugins\cvsIntegration\lib, I see the CVS jars.

I guess I can download an external client, but I'd love to get this working.

This is 14.1.4 on Windows 7

Thanks very much.

Comment: Do you use `Ant`? Does `Ant` know where to find `CVS`?

Comment: I use the bundled ant that comes with the Intellij ant plugin.  But it does not use cvs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an :ext: CVS root, make sure you have the *Use internal SSH implementation* checkbox (in the settings of the CVS Root) enabled.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem; I do the following:

1. Uninstall the Intellij IDE completely.
2. Reinstall the newer version of IntelliJ

then the IDE work properly.